# Unable to install KB2267602 until Edge was updated

Tags: windows-update, microsoft-edge

Can the update status of Edge affect Windows Update itself?

BACKGROUND:
Repeated failed attempts to install KB2267602 on Windows 10 x64 where 21H2 has not yet been installed. The following did not help:

```
 Open Elevated Command Prompt
 
 Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /CheckHealth 
 Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image> /ScanHealth 
 Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth
 
 sfc /SCANNOW
  [no problems detected]
 Restart system
```

Also followed the suggestions here:

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/all/windows-update-error-0x80070643/3bad0495-dabb-4e3f-91a7-aaf992ef537a

But after opening Edge and updating Edge, I checked for Windows updates once again, and KB2267602 was gone.

Was this a coincidence or can the update status of Edge affect Windows Update itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

KB2267602 is a new definition update for Windows Defender Antivirus,
so I don't see the connection between it and Edge.
I think it's more likely that the problematic KB2267602 update itself
was quietly improved by Microsoft, meaning replaced, while you were
updating Edge.

Users had problems with KB2267602 since April 2021, as seen in the post
[Windows 10 Updates - KB2267602 Security Intelligence update Fails to Install](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/343287/windows-10-updates-from-39ball-of-confusion39-to-f.html),
where users have remarked on this update having pretty strange
dependencies.

This is then an old update from one year ago that nowadays may conflict
with newer updates. I don't think that there is any special reason to
install it, as it surely was superseded since then.

A user in the linked post has remarked that the best way to insure
that the Windows Defender signatures were up to date is to run an
elevated CMD and enter these commands:

```
cd %ProgramFiles%\Windows Defender
MpCmdRun.exe -removedefinitions -dynamicsignatures
MpCmdRun.exe -SignatureUpdate
```

Answer (score -1):

Can not comment, so in addition to @harrymc - after Windows 10 restore point, had same problem and I was not able to run his commands. There was **0x800106ba** error
Solved by:

1. found in services "Microsoft Defender Antivirus Service", it was not running
2. opened it's properties and found "Executable path:"C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows Defender\Platform\4.18.1234.5-0\MsMpEng.exe""
3. opened C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows Defender\Platform\ and there was no such folder from p.2;
4. copied one of folders and renamed it to  "4.18.1234.5-0" and then I have started service
5. only after that I was able to run Harrys commands and then run Update